# How to remove this character

Tags: php, regex

I have an Excel file I'm extracting data from. Part of the text contains the character shown below. I've tried both preg_match and str_replace but they don't catch it. I'm assuming it is because I need the code for that character but I can't find that anywhere.

```
    †
```

The actual line is below. Note that the missing closing span is how the file has it.

```
    <p><span style="font-size:11px">†Combined weight of 1/2 of total weight</p>
```

These are the commands I've tried.

```
    $text = preg_replace("†",'',$text);
    $text = str_replace("†",'',$text);
```

Would someone explain how to remove that character, please?

Comment: Check encoding of the input and your PHP file.

Comment: The php file is UTF-8. I'm not sure how to check the input but I tried the following but the result was false.  echo mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true) ;

Comment: UTF-8 has possible 2 modes of saving; one *with* a BOM (byte order mark) and one *without*. It could make a difference. @user3052443

Comment: Based on some guesswork I found that the character's [HEX code is `2020`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2020/index.htm), which just so happens to be the hex code of the space character twice. I would suggest reading the file as ASCII-encoded. If you open the file in Notepad++ you should be able to see the encoding in the Encoding menu.

Comment: I checked the file for a BOM but it wasn't there. I tried  $text = preg_replace("/2020/",'', $text);  but it didn't help. I found a post that said to use $text = str_replace(chr(0), "", $text); to convert to ascii but that didn't help either.

Comment: long shot (will also remove other symbols e.g. &euro; ): $cleaned = filter_var($yourString, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH)

Comment: That seems to have done it. I will have to run it on the full file and check that nothing I need has been deleted but the ones I checked now look fine. Thank you for this fix. I've been fighting it for weeks.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Could you mark it as accepted answer if it works on your full file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHPs built in filters e.g.

`$cleaned = filter_var($yourString, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);`

This should enable you to remove non ASCII characters (simplistically those above Hex 7E) such as dagger symbol without knowing their numeric code. However; it will also remove other non-ASCII characters such as the Euro currency symbol. If these are used and needed you would have to find some way of storing and reapplying these to your string.